How to find if CUDA Toolkit 12 supports which capability?
CUDA Toolkit Documentation v12.0 apparently has no information which compute capabilities are supported. It only says "you will need CUDA-capable GPU".

1.1. System Requirements
To use NVIDIA CUDA on your system, you will need the following installed:

CUDA-capable GPU


CUDA 12.6 Update 3 Release Notes has no information either.
Then, how user can know if we can use CUDA 12.x for the GPU we have?

Have you confirmed where it is or isn't a CUDA-capable GPU?
